# How do I implement changing background themes in Flutter with SVG images?

Tags: flutter, svg

How to use SVG background in Flutter with changing themes?
I have two themes (dark and light) they switch by button. The bottom line is that you need to download an SVG that will change the background color when you change the theme. For example, in the Telegram application, when you change the theme, the background color also changes. How can this be done?

I tried a lot, I thought the problem was in SVG, but no.
I use this code:

```
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.asset(
           "images/Sprinkle.svg",
              alignment: Alignment.center,
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
           fit: BoxFit.cover,

         ),
```

Theme

```
void main() {
  runApp(ThemeSettings());
}

class ThemeSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThemeSettingsState createState() => _ThemeSettingsState();

  /// InheritedWidget style accessor to our State object.
  /// We can call this static method from any descendant context to find our
  /// State object and switch the themeMode field value & call for a rebuild.
  static _ThemeSettingsState of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_ThemeSettingsState>()!;
}

/// Our State object
class _ThemeSettingsState extends State<ThemeSettings> {
  /// 1) our themeMode "state" field
  ThemeMode _themeMode = ThemeMode.system;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFC47171),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                //background: Color(0xFF9B9999),
                brightness: Brightness.light,
                primary: Colors.black,
                error: Colors.grey,
                secondary: Colors.black,
                onPrimary: Colors.blue,
                onError: Colors.redAccent,
                surface: Colors.red,
                onSecondary: Colors.red,
                onBackground: Colors.redAccent,
                onSurface: Colors.black)
            .copyWith(secondary: Colors.red),
        primaryIconTheme:
            Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF222B38),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                //background: Color(0xFF222B38),
                brightness: Brightness.dark,
                primary: Colors.white,
                error: Colors.grey,
                secondary: Color(0xFF676D7A),
                onPrimary: Colors.blue,
                //onError: Colors.redAccent,
                surface: Color(0xFF2C3544),
                //onSecondary: Colors.red,
                //onBackground: Colors.redAccent,
                onSurface: Color(0xFF00A6FF)),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      themeMode: _themeMode,
      // 2) ← ← ← use "state" field here //////////////
      home: Second_Screen(),
    );
  }

  /// 3) Call this to change theme from any context using "of" accessor
  /// e.g.:
  /// MyApp.of(context).changeTheme(ThemeMode.dark);
  void changeTheme(ThemeMode themeMode) {
    setState(() {
      _themeMode = themeMode;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have solved.BUt also posting this answer.

```
class Themes {
  final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(31, 88, 130, 144),
    expansionTileTheme: const ExpansionTileThemeData(
      textColor: Colors.white,
      collapsedTextColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    primaryColor: Colors.grey,
   
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: AppColors.darkAppBarColor),
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.white),
  );

  final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    // scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(31, 88, 130, 144),
    expansionTileTheme: const ExpansionTileThemeData(
      textColor: Colors.white,
      collapsedTextColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    primaryColor: Colors.grey,
   
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: AppColors.darkAppBarColor),
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.white),
  );
}


return GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
      
        theme: Themes().lightTheme,
        darkTheme: Themes().darkTheme,
        
        themeMode: themeMode,
        home: HomePage()
        // const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
```

now appy the theme to your svg as:

```
SvgPicture.asset("assets/quote_right.svg",
                height: 40, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
```